# How to place double quotes inside the double quotes of string.IndexOf() function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a String I want to get the index of the `"id:"` i.e the id along with the double quotes.

How I am supposed to do so inside C# `string.IndexOf` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"` is an [`escape sequence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

If you want to use a double quotation mark in your string, you should use `\"` instead.

For example;

```
int index = yourstring.IndexOf("\"id:\"");
```

Remember, [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method gets *zero-based index* of the first occurrence of the your string.

Comment: @user3136399 You are quite welcome. If one of these answer solve your problem, please consider to accept one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 5):

This will get the *index* of the string you want:

```
var idx = input.IndexOf("\"id:\"");
```

if you wanted to pull it out you'd do something like this maybe:

```
var idx = input.IndexOf("\"id:\"");
var val = input.Substring(idx, len);
```

where `len` is either a statically known length or also calculated by another `IndexOf` statement.

Honestly, this could also be done with a `Regex`, and if an example were available a `Regex` may be the right approach because you're presumably trying to get the actual value here and it's presumably JSON you're reading.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple approach: If you know double quote is before the Id then take index of id - 1?

```
string myString = @"String with ""id:"" in it";
var indexOfId = myString.IndexOf("id:") - 1;

Console.WriteLine(@"Index of ""id:"" is {0}", indexOfId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, if this is a JSON string, and you have .NET 4 or higher available, you can ask .NET to deserialize the string for you rather than parsing by hand: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620210/58063).

Alternatively you might consider [Json.NET](http://json.net) if you're working very heavily with JSON.

Otherwise, as others note, you need to [escape the quotes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx), so for example:

```
text.IndexOf("\"id:\"")
text.IndexOf(@"""id:""")
```

or for overengineered legiblity:

```
string Quoted(string text)
{
    return "\"" + text + "\""; // generates unnecessary garbage
}

text.IndexOf(Quoted("id:"))
```